# How to edit twitter bootstrap files in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I'm trying to find the twitter-bootstrap files in my rails app ('bootstrap-sass', '2.0.0'), as I need to make a change directly to the bootstrap-responsive.css file, however, I can't find it.

I have bootstrap up and running, but can't seem to find the bootstrap files.  How do I locate the bootstrap-responsive.css file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`bootstap-sass`](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass) gem uses the [Rails 3.2 asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) to inject the necessary stylesheets into your app. The actual stylesheet files are located in the [gem installation directory](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/vendor/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap-responsive.scss), not in your project itself.

Depending on what you want to change, you can either:

1. Copy the [`_bootstrap-responsive.scss`](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/vendor/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap-responsive.scss) file from the gem into your `app/assets` directory and edit it there.
2. Customize the necessary [Bootstrap variables](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/less.html#variables) before loading up Bootstrap in your application.scss file:

   ```
   $btnPrimaryBackground: #f00;
   @import "bootstrap";
   ```

Comment: thanks.  should the file be in my vendor/assets/stylesheets folder or should i just copy the _bootstrap-responsive.scss file into my app/assets directory and edit it?  for some reason, the file isn't even showing in my vendor/assets/stylesheets folder even though bootstrap works.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Try looking under

```
app/assets/stylesheets
```

Here's an example

```
https://github.com/joliss/solitr/tree/master/app/assets/stylesheets
```

---

I'm not too familiar with the structure of rails apps but did you create a local copy or are you using the bootstrap files being hosted directly by github? You should be able to figure that out by checking one of your launched html pages and viewing the source, looking for something like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.3.0/bootstrap.min.css">
```

If it's a local page, there should be a directory somewhere in your rails app where the files are stored - perhaps there's a 'static' folder or something similar? Try file-searching for it, good chance you might find it.

(I use Django/Python for web projects but I'll look into Rails a bit and see if I find anything)

Comment: On the page source, they show as being in assets/bootstrap, but they don't appear in the folder. The files also do not show up on my local computer search, even though the files load on localhost.